# Trying to save a fraction to SQLite in Android Studio in a TEXT but getting 1 in display

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to save "1/8", "1/6", "1/4", "1/3", and "1/2" to a table and display it. Whenever I display it, it shows "1". I have tested what is sent to be saved and I know the fractions as a String are fine so I know it probably has something to do with SQLite. I'm new to SQLite so it might be a simple fix but any help is appreciated. Here is the code for the DBHelper. CHALLENGE_RATING is where I hit this problem.

```
package com.example.android.tabletoprpgexperiencetrackerapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SessionDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sessionlist.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public SessionDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        final String SQL_CREATE_SESSIONLIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                SessionContract.SessionEntry.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                SessionContract.SessionEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                SessionContract.SessionEntry.COLUMN_SESSION_NUMBER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                SessionContract.SessionEntry.COLUMN_CREATURE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                SessionContract.SessionEntry.COLUMN_CHALLENGE_RATING + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                SessionContract.SessionEntry.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                SessionContract.SessionEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                SessionContract.SessionEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
                ");";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_SESSIONLIST_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int il){
       sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SessionContract.SessionEntry.TABLE_NAME);
       onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
   }
```

}

Not sure if this affects anything but I initially had CHALLENGE_RATING saving as an INTEGER but even after dropping the table to reset it after changing it to TEXT didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess you are not retrieving them as strings.

The thing with SQLite is that you can save any type of value in any type of column and with the SQLite in Android retrieve most types as most types. This can be good but can also be confusing.

This is explained here [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

The following adaptation of the code you have supplied does what you want :-

### SessionDBHelper :-

```
public class SessionDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sessionlist.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "session";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_SESSION_NUMBER = "session_number";
    public static final String COLUMN_CREATURE_NAME = "creature_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHALLENGE_RATING = "challenge_rating";
    public static final String COLUMN_EXPERIENCE = "experience";
    public static final String COLUMN_QUANTITY = "quantity";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

    public SessionDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        final String SQL_CREATE_SESSIONLIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_SESSION_NUMBER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_CREATURE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_CHALLENGE_RATING + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_EXPERIENCE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_QUANTITY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
                ");";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_SESSIONLIST_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int il){
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public long insertSession(int session_number, String creature_name, String challeng_rating, int experience, int quantity) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_SESSION_NUMBER, session_number);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CREATURE_NAME,creature_name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CHALLENGE_RATING,challeng_rating);
        cv.put(COLUMN_EXPERIENCE,experience);
        cv.put(COLUMN_QUANTITY,quantity);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getSessions() {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- As you see I've replaced your references to the Session class etc with CONSTANTS defined in the **SessionDBHelper** class for my convenience. They are not at all relevant so keep your very well structured use.
- I've added two methods `insertSession` and `getSessions`. So sessions can be inserted and all sessions can be retrieved.

### Invoking (from an activity in this case) :-

```
    SessionDBHelper dbhlpr = new SessionDBHelper(this);

    dbhlpr.insertSession(100,"Fred","1/2",10,1);
    dbhlpr.insertSession(123,"Bert","1/8",16,2);
    dbhlpr.insertSession(546,"Harold","1/236",54,3);
    dbhlpr.insertSession(654,"Alan","1/16",23,7);

    Cursor csr = dbhlpr.getSessions();
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("SESSIONINFO",
                "Session ID =" + String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(SessionDBHelper.COLUMN_ID))) +
                        "\n\tChallange Rating as String = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SessionDBHelper.COLUMN_CHALLENGE_RATING)) +
                        "\n\tChallenge Rating as Integer = " + csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(SessionDBHelper.COLUMN_CHALLENGE_RATING)) +
                        "\n\tChallenge Rating as Double = " + csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(SessionDBHelper.COLUMN_CHALLENGE_RATING))
        );
    }
    csr.close();
```

- This will insert 4 Sessions (per run) and then output the ID column and the ChallengeRating column using 3 retrieval types 1) as a String (using `getString`), 2) as an Integer (using `getInt`) and 3 as a Double (using `getDouble`).

### Result :-

```
04-18 20:58:41.691 1206-1206/soanswers.soanswers D/SESSIONINFO: Session ID =1
        Challange Rating as String = 1/2
        Challenge Rating as Integer = 1
        Challenge Rating as Double = 1.0
    Session ID =2
        Challange Rating as String = 1/8
        Challenge Rating as Integer = 1
        Challenge Rating as Double = 1.0
    Session ID =3
        Challange Rating as String = 1/236
        Challenge Rating as Integer = 1
        Challenge Rating as Double = 1.0
    Session ID =4
        Challange Rating as String = 1/16
        Challenge Rating as Integer = 1
        Challenge Rating as Double = 1.0
```

As you can see `getString` is what you want, `getInt` matches what you got.

### Fix

It would appear that all you need to do is use **`getString`** instead of **`getInt`**.